How is Vedanga jyotisha different from Phalajyotisha? Which planets are used to calculate timing of Yajnas in Vedanga jyotisha?
I have heard that Rahu Ketu in Vedanga Jyotisha are sun and moons shadows respectively.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
